# Where was this iPad Air 2 wallpaper photo taken? (Glacier, Lake, Altitude…)

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, photography

On the Apple website, [iPads' section](http://www.apple.com/ipad-air-2/) one device features a wonderful background:

[image: Screenshot I could take from the webpage]

I tried using Google Images reverse search (which would just send me back to the Apple website, logical) and also asked a couple of people at Apple (with no success).

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Google images was not helpful because the photo is squeezed, this is the [original photo](http://cl.ly/Y4ZZ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gokyo Lake, Himalaya Mountains, Nepal.

Sources: [1](http://nepalladakh.com/everest-base-camp-and-gokyo-lake-trek/), [2](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/asia/travel-tips-and-articles/77626), [3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/174179272X).

Comment: This was a tough one...

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, 'un-squezeed' the height looks a tad less impressive, yet it's still absolutely wonderful, really want to trek there!
I am a bit curious, you said this was a tough one: how did you do to find it? Did you know the place already or did you 'un-squeezed' the image?

Comment: @universalTraveller I start searching until I found the unsqueezed version, then things got easier.